# Using a for loop across columns with similar names

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to use the `tidyverse` (`purrr`) package to run a `for loop` across my dataset. I want to check whether some number of conditions are true across certain columns along the dataset. Note, I am trying to become more familiar with tidyverse and its functions rather than rely on Base R.

Here is the code that I want to write a for loop for.

```
 nrow(subset(data, flwr_clstr1>1 & bud_clstr1==0))
 nrow(subset(data, flwr_clstr2>1 & bud_clstr2==0))
 nrow(subset(data, flwr_clstr3>1 & bud_clstr3==0))
```

I have columns of data (in this case, it would be flwr_clstr) that are similar, but differ by the last digit. Also, if there is another way to use `tidyverse` to check these 'conditions', that would be great too.

Here is my attempt at the for loop.

```
 check1 <- vector("double", ncol(data_phen))
       for (i in seq_along(data_phen)) {
     check[[i]] <- nrow(subset(data, flwr_clstr[[i]]>1 & bud_clstr[[i]]==0))
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to help if you could provide a reproducible example, however I created a sample of what your data might look like based on my understanding.

We can use `map2_int` from `purrr` since we are trying to count number of rows in each pair of columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map2_int(data %>% select(starts_with("flwr_clstr")), 
         data %>% select(starts_with("bud_clstr")), 
         ~sum(.x  > 1 & .y == 0))  %>% unname()

#[1] 2 3 1
```

---

However, base R isn't that bad either. This can be solved using `mapply`

```
col1 <- grep("^flwr_clstr", names(data))
col2 <- grep("^bud_clstr", names(data))
mapply(function(x, y) sum(x > 1 & y == 0), data[col1], data[col2])
```

**data**

Assuming you have equal number of columns for both `"flwr_clstr.."` and `"bud_clstr.."`

```
data <- data.frame(flwr_clstr1 = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 0), flwr_clstr2 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 0),
  flwr_clstr3 = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1), bud_clstr1 = 0, bud_clstr2 = 0,bud_clstr3 = 0)
```

which looks like

```
data
#  flwr_clstr1 flwr_clstr2 flwr_clstr3 bud_clstr1 bud_clstr2 bud_clstr3
#1           2           2           1          0          0          0
#2           1           2           1          0          0          0
#3           2           2           2          0          0          0
#4           1           1           1          0          0          0
#5           0           0           1          0          0          0
```

Comment: Yes, should have provided a sample dataset. Will do in the future! Also, there are equal columns for both parameters. Code works.. thank you!